# Import file failed to greenplum because of one line of data on navicate

Tags: greenplum

```
When importing a file into Greenplum,one lines fails,and the whole file is not imported successfully.Is there a way can skip the wrong line and import other data into Greenplum successfully?
Here are my SQL execution and error messages:
```

copy cjh_test from '/gp_wkspace/outputs/base_tables/error_data_test.csv' using delimiters ',';

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "FE00F760B39BD3756BCFF30000000600"
CONTEXT:  COPY cjh_test, line 81, column local_city: "FE00F760B39BD3756BCFF30000000600"

Answer (score 1):

Greenplum has an extension to the COPY command that lets you log errors and set up a certain amount of errors that can occur that won't stop the load.  Here is an example from the documentation for the COPY command:

```
COPY sales FROM '/home/usr1/sql/sales_data' LOG ERRORS 
   SEGMENT REJECT LIMIT 10 ROWS;
```

That tells COPY that 10 bad rows can be ignored without stopping the load.   The reject limit can be # of rows or a percentage of the load file.  You can check the full syntax in psql with:  \h copy

If you are loading a very large file into Greenplum, I would suggest looking at gpload or gpfdist (which also support the segment reject limit syntax).  COPY is single threaded through the master server where gpload/gpfdist load the data in parallel to all segments.   COPY will be faster for smaller load files and the others will be faster for millions of rows in a load file(s).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!This command is pretty useful and solved my problem,I have more than four milions rows in the file,i'll try gpload realize file load